# Can I read a serial console over USB (not with an adapter)?

Tags: linux, usb, console, serial-port

I'm working with a device that provides serial console access via a USB-B port. My workstation is a laptop running Linux Mint 17.1.

Previously, I was able to access the serial console from my laptop using minicom over a USB-A(Male) to DB9(Female) adapter connected to a DB9(M) to USB-B(M) adapter, which I plugged directly into the device. I was able to read from and write to the serial console at /dev/ttyUSB0.

I no longer have the DB9(M) to USB-B(M) adapter, which I can't find for sale anywhere online.

In its place, I've tried using a DB9(M) to USB-A(M) adapter with a USB-A bridge to a standard USB-A(M) to USB-B(M) cable. The device still shows up in /dev, but I'm unable to read from or write to the serial console. For all I know, this is essentially equivalent to using a standard USB cable.

The device does not appear in /dev when I try connecting it to my laptop using a standard USB-A to USB-B cable. However, when I run dmesg, I see the following:

```
usb 3-2: new low-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
```

So it seems the device is recognized by the OS, but no corresponding node in /dev is created.

I'm wondering whether there's a way to access a serial console from my laptop directly over a USB A-B cable, without an adapter.

Thanks for any help, I know this probably isn't exciting stuff.

Comment: I just purchased such an adapter ... ChipiX from FTDI is pretty inexpensive